# Jquery Textbox php session validation

Tags: php, html, jquery

```
 var x =  document.forms["myForm"]["Code2"].value;
  if (x == "") {
    alert("You cannot enter same value as previous one.");
    return false;
  }
```

How can i add PHP session to (x == "") so Jquery can validate previous value with current one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

index.php:

```
<?php $value=(isset($_SESSION['value']))?$_SESSION['value']:''; ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
var xvalue = '<?php echo $value;?>';
    </script>
```

javascript file:

```
 var x =  document.forms["myForm"]["Code2"].value;
  if (x == xvalue) {
    alert("You cannot enter same value as previous one.");
    return false;
  }
```